# How can I checkout a SVN-URL in an Eclipse workspace?

Tags: eclipse, svn

I use Eclipse Neon with the SVN-Plugin.
Our team works with branches.
If I want to get the code of the branch in my Workspace I have two options:

- In the SVN-View I browse my way to the destination and click checkout.
- I use a terminal, svn checkout and File->import existing projects into Workspace

  > svn co 
  >   http://subversion.abc.de/prjAbc/branches/2018/20180101abc/branch3/ 
  >   ./prjAbc -r 'HEAD'

Is there a lazier way to dump a url into eclipse and make it checkout a 
svn-branch into the workspace?

Comment: In Subversive (there are two SVN pug-ins: Subversive and Subclipse) you can do _File > Import...: SVN > Project from SVN_. As far as I know, just dropping a URL onto Eclipse does only work for Git.

Comment: there are some clumsy dialogs but still way better than my standard procedure. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse [Subversive](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/subversive-svn-team-provider) you can do the following (in the alternative Eclipse plugin [Subclipse](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/subclipse) it probably works similarly):

- ***File > Import...: SVN > Project from SVN***

or use Quick Access:

- Hit **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>** and enter **`Import (Project from SVN)`**

As far as I know, just dropping a URL onto Eclipse does only work for Git.

Comment: Nice! This will be useful.